# Get machine properties

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to write a program that will identify a machine( for licensing purposes), I tought about getting the following information and to compile an xml file with this data:

1. MAC address.
2. CPU data (serial, manufacture, etc)
3. MotherBoard Identification. (serial, manufacture, etc)

can someone refer me to a lib that provide such information - I write my program in c++ and have troubles to find such a lib.

Should I dig in the registry for this information?

Many Thanks,
ofer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx) and getting the motherboard's serial number should be enough (the other options are less secure, since an old computer may not have a network adapter and/or the CPU can be changed more likely than the motherboard).

Comment: It's worth noting that there may be multiple MAC addresses and they can change pretty frequently (e.g. a built-in WiFi card in a notebook, internally connected via USB, may totally disappear when not in use);

Comment: ..and also that WMI can be disabled on a target machine, and is not present on older systems (Win2K, Win9x). But, still, WMI is the best bet in terms of compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

GetAdaptersInfo() will give you the MAC address.  Here's an example of how to use it for this purpose.

```
/** *************************************

  return string containing first MAC address on computer

  NOTE: requires adding Iphlpapi.lib to project

 */
string GetMac()
{
    char data[4096];
    ZeroMemory( data, 4096 );
     unsigned long  len = 4000;
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pinfo = ( PIP_ADAPTER_INFO ) data;
    char sbuf[20];
    string sret;

    DWORD ret = GetAdaptersInfo( pinfo, &len );
    if( ret != ERROR_SUCCESS )
        return string("**ERROR**");

    for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++ ) {
        sprintf(sbuf,"%02X-",pinfo->Address[k]);
        sret += sbuf;
    }
    sprintf(sbuf,"%02X",pinfo->Address[5]);
    sret += sbuf;

    return( sret );
}
```

For an example of a complete system to do this sort of thing, check out Manuele Sicuteri's [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/softwarekey.aspx) on CodeProject.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use WMI (slow, not installed on NT)
Use standard Win32 apis

See news://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
where all this has been answered for decades (C /++ code)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Links or essential excerpts would be appreciated. Your answer as-is is kinda useless.

Comment: Please can you point to specific win32 API which should be used?